# Visio auto run shape report on every page of a Visio document

Tags: vba, visio

I have a simple shape report that gets the shape displaytext, height, width, PinX, PinY: I need to run this report on each page and save it with the page name as the file name and as html. I'm new and this VBA script will only be used for 40 Visio documents. Can anyone help me with this?

The report gets and save the exact information I need and I already have a data migration tool to parse that data and import it into a web SQL server.
what I need is for this report to run on every page (automation) get the page name and export the html file named from the page name and save it in a folder. I was hoping to do this with VBA in Visio. the problem is I do not know vba enough to automate this. I tried using chat4 but I keep getting errors.

Here is the script I've tried (about ten versions of this)

```vb
Sub ExportReportToHTML()
  Dim MyPage As Page
  Dim ReportName As String
  Dim HTMLFile As String
  Dim fs As Object
  Dim DirectoryPath As String

  ' Create a FileSystemObject
  Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  ' Set the directory path
  DirectoryPath = "C:\Users\duanemorris\Desktop\Visio Data\"

  ' Check if the directory exists, if not then create it
  If Not fs.FolderExists(DirectoryPath) Then
    fs.CreateFolder (DirectoryPath)
  End If

  ' Set the report name
  ReportName = "Dataextract"

  ' Loop through all pages in the document
  For Each MyPage In ActiveDocument.Pages

    ' Set the HTML file name based on the page name after removing invalid characters
    HTMLFile = DirectoryPath & ReplaceInvalidCharacters(MyPage.Name) & ".html"

    ' Run the report and export it to an HTML file
    MyPage.AddShapesReport(ReportName).ExportAsFixedFormat visFixedFormatHTML, HTMLFile, visDocExIntentPrint

  Next MyPage

End Sub
```

```
Function ReplaceInvalidCharacters(ByVal str As String) As String
   Dim InvalidChars As Variant
   Dim i As Integer

   InvalidChars = Array("/", "\", ":", "*", "?", """", "<", ">", "|") ' List of invalid characters.

   For i = LBound(InvalidChars) To UBound(InvalidChars)
      str = Replace(str, InvalidChars(i), "") ' Replace invalid character with nothing.
   Next i

   ReplaceInvalidCharacters = str

End Function
```

Here is the output html that I get from the report (Dataextract)

the file is Report_10.html

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD><META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/css; charset=utf-8"/><STYLE TYPE="text/css">    H1
    {   font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 118%;
        color: #4275BD; 
    }   
    TH
    {   font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 100%;
        color: #000000; 
        background: #B5C7E7;
    }   
    SPAN
    {   font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #009999;
    }
    TD
    {   font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        text-align: right;  
        font-size: 80%;
        color: #000000; 
        background: #EFF3E7;    
    }   
    DIV
    {   font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 115%;
        color: #4275BD;
    }
</STYLE></HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1 class="visrptTitle">Report_1</H1>
        <TABLE CELLPADDING="10" ALIGN="center" SUMMARY="">
            <TR>
                <TH class="visrptHeader">Displayed Text</TH>
                <TH class="visrptHeader">Height</TH>
                <TH class="visrptHeader">Width</TH>
                <TH class="visrptHeader">X Location</TH>
                <TH class="visrptHeader">Y Location</TH>
            </TR>
            <TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">9.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">7.88 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.19 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">5.41 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.20 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.49 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.73 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.48 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.07 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.50 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.32 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">5.80 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.19 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">6.86 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.49 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.06 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.49 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.32 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">3.16 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.11 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">6.86 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">3.15 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.19 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.50 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.32 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.49 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.06 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.49 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.73 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">5.80 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.07 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.50 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.73 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">3.15 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.06 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.31 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">6.83 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">5.80 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">Pulmonary Embolus (PE) - Typical presentation of SOB, tachycardia, risk factors.  EtCO2 can present with normal waveform appearance and a lower numeric value due to respiratory rate and decrease perfusion to lungs. If the PE is small you may see no change.  Small PE may demonstrate no change in EtCO2 values and should not be used as a single assessment tool for assessment of a PE
<BR></BR>
                    <BR></BR>Pregnant Patients - compression of the vena cava restricts blood flow back to the heart and lungs which can cause decreases in EtCO2 due to decrease perfusion.
<BR></BR>Note: Shark-fin waveform appearance in pregnant patients can be a normal finding and does not specifically indicate bronchoconstriction.
<BR></BR>
                    <BR></BR>Rescue Airway Device – Rescue Airway Devices - Used to confirm adequate ventilation. without other evidence of                    bronchoconstriction as this may be a normal finding.
<BR></BR>
                    <BR></BR>Remember
<BR></BR>  Capnography assesses ventilation
<BR></BR>  It confirms adequate ventilation – not a confirmed secured airway!!!!
<BR></BR>  You have to have adequate perfusion
<BR></BR>  Changes are immediate long before pulse oximetry
<BR></BR>  You need to use it to be comfortable with it
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.88 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">7.63 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.19 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">8.54 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">Capnography Wave Forms
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">7.50 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.11 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">6.72 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">References
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.98 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.88 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.48 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">(1) Davis, DP.,Dunford,JV. Inadvertent Hyperventilation following Paramedic RSI of Severely Head-injured Patients.
<BR></BR>Acad Emerg Med. Vol. 10, No. 5 446. 2003
<BR></BR>(2) Weil, M. Cardiac Output and End-Tidal Carbon Dioxide. Critical Care Medicine, November 1985
<BR></BR>(3) Singh Amar. Comparing the Ability of Colormetric and Digital Waveform End Tidal Capnography to Verify ET tube placement. Academic Emergency Medicine Vol. 10 No. 5 466-467
<BR></BR>(4) Levine R. End-tidal Co2 and outcome of out-of-hospital cardiac arrest. New England Journal of Medicine. July 997;337:301-306
<BR></BR>(5) Phillips 2003
<BR></BR>(6) Fearon D., Steele D. End-tidal CO2 predicts the presence and severity of Acidosis in Children. Academic Emergency
<BR></BR>Medicine Vol 9 No. 12 1373-1378
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.71 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">7.63 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.19 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.58 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">8.00 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">10.75 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">Reference
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.50 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.00 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">10.56 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">Reference
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.50 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">7.50 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">10.56 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">Capnography-Information/Waveforms
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">8.00 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">10.56 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">-</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">8.00 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.50 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">Responsoft EMS Protocols
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.67 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">1.58 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">Page 229
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.67 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">4.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
            </TR><TR><TD class="visrptRowItem">10/13/2020
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.25 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">2.67 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">6.92 in.
</TD>
                <TD class="visrptRowItem">0.38 in.
</TD>
            </TR></TABLE>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the macro recorder and manually executing the Shape Report?